# Subscribing to event while creating object in C#

Tags: c#, events

In C# (.NET 4.5) I would like to subscribe to an event while I'm creating an object.

The following, of course, would work:

```
CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
c.Name = "TheCheckBox";
c.Checked += c_Checked;
```

But want to find out if it's possible to do something along the lines of:

```
CheckBox c = new CheckBox() {
    Name = "TheCheckBox",
    Checked += c_Checked
}
```

*Post-discussion edit:* This is in order to accomplish is something like:

```
MyUniformGrid.Add(new CheckBox() {
    Name = "TheCheckBox",
    Checked += CheckHandler
});
```

Comment: if it's your own controls you should be able to have a `Func<>` as argument to the constructor and set it up there

Comment: @Default could you post an answer with example code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, unfortunately event subscription isn't supported within object initializers. It would make it *really* simple to create GUIs in some cases, but no...

The half-way house is:

```
Checkbox c = new CheckBox { Name = "TheCheckBox" };
c.Checked += c_Checked;
```

(Ideally renaming `c_Checked` to a name which is actually meaningful - I hate the VS-generated names here...)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm aware of the half-way solution, but it doesn't work for me. What I wanted to do was something like `MyUniformGrid.Add(new CheckBox() { Checked += CheckHandler });`.

Comment: @baytas: Right - it won't, basically. You could hook up an extension method to allow: `MyUniformGrid.Add(new CheckBox().With(c => c.Checked += CheckHandler))` if that would help...

Comment: @PLB I agree. I'm actually not motivated to reduce the number of lines in my code. Rather, I have a `UniformGrid` control which I populate with `CheckBox`es using a `for` loop, and running `CheckBox c = new CheckBox()` inside a loop just feels wrong.

Comment: @baytas: Why does it feel wrong? There's nothing wrong at all with declaring a variable in a loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet perhaps "ugly" rather than "wrong" would have been a better word choice.

Comment: @baytas: It's not even ugly. It's entirely reasonable. While I'd like the object initializer syntax to support it, I don't think there's anything wrong with breaking out another local variable in a loop here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over your controls you could always set up the eventhandler in the constructor. Something like:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Checkbox checkbox = new Checkbox(OnChecked);
        checkbox.TriggerChecked();
    }

    private static void OnChecked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("triggered event");
    }
}

public class Checkbox
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Checked;

    public Checkbox(EventHandler<EventArgs> eventHandler)
    {
        Checked += eventHandler;
    }


    public void TriggerChecked()
    {
        var handler = Checked;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case I'm better off just doing things the usual way (first code block in the question). Nevertheless, this is new to me and I'm always happy to learn new stuff. Thank you for showing.